# Categorization Logic for DateTime in SQL

Tags: sql-server

A third party system (Sensor) will be sending information (SensorID and Datetime) whenever it identifies a movement from a place.

```
SensorID    DatetimeInformation
    1           3/20/2017 07:05
    1           3/20/2017 07:15
    1           3/20/2017 07:35
    1           3/20/2017 07:55
    2           3/20/2017 07:11
    2           3/20/2017 07:19
    2           3/20/2017 07:45
    2           3/20/2017 07:58
```

I would like to write a SQL logic seperately to categorize the above information after every 1 hour

```
SensorID    Date            TimeDuration    DateTimeInformationList (store as VarBinary(Max))
1           3/20/2017        7AM - 8AM      3/20/2017 07:05, 3/20/2017 07:15 ,3/20/2017 07:35,3/20/2017 07:55
2           3/20/2017        7AM - 8AM      3/20/2017 07:11, 3/20/2017 07:19 ,3/20/2017 07:45,3/20/2017 07:58
```

Comment: look at this post : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (SensorID int,DatetimeInformation datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
( 1 ,'3/20/2017 07:05'),
( 1 ,'3/20/2017 07:15'),
( 1 ,'3/20/2017 07:35'),
( 1 ,'3/20/2017 07:55'),
( 2 ,'3/20/2017 07:11'),
( 2 ,'3/20/2017 07:19'),
( 2 ,'3/20/2017 07:45'),
( 2 ,'3/20/2017 07:58')

;with cte as (
        Select SensorID
              ,MinDT        = Min(DatetimeInformation)
              ,MaxDT        = Max(DatetimeInformation)
        From  @YourTable
        Group By SensorID
                ,Convert(date,DatetimeInformation)
                ,DatePart(HOUR,DatetimeInformation)
)
Select SensorID
      ,Date  = Convert(date,MinDT)
      ,TimeDuration = Format(MinDT,'htt')+ ' - ' + Format(DateAdd(HOUR,1,minDT),'htt')
      ,DateTimeInformationList = Stuff((Select ', ' +Format(DatetimeInformation,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm') 
                                         From  @YourTable 
                                         Where SensorID=A.SensorID 
                                           and DatetimeInformation between A.MinDT and A.MaxDT  
                                         Order By DatetimeInformation 
                                         For XML Path ('')
                                       ),1,2,'')
 from  cte A
```

Returns

```
SensorID    Date         TimeDuration   DateTimeInformationList
1           2017-03-20   7AM - 8AM      3/20/2017 7:05, 3/20/2017 7:15, 3/20/2017 7:35, 3/20/2017 7:55
2           2017-03-20   7AM - 8AM      3/20/2017 7:11, 3/20/2017 7:19, 3/20/2017 7:45, 3/20/2017 7:58
```

Comment: This works wonderfully. Is it possible to find the average time gap(minutes or seconds) for all the DatetimeInformationList for that TimeDuration ?

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, pDataDate, DatetimeInformation)
    FROM    (
       SELECT  *,
       LAG(DatetimeInformation) OVER (ORDER BY DatetimeInformation) pDataDate
       From  TestSensor 
                                         Where SensorID=A.SensorID 
                                           and DatetimeInformation between A.MinDT and A.MaxDT
      ) q
      WHERE   pDataDate IS NOT NULL